# Norm of composition of linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am trying to prove that for normed vector spaces $U$, $V$, and $W$ with $S : U \rightarrow V$ and $T : V \rightarrow W$ linear maps. We have  $||T \circ  S|| \leq || T|| \cdot ||S||$.

I have that $\|T\|=\sup \{\|T f\|: f \in V \text { and }\|f\| \leq 1\}$ and $\|T \circ S \|=\sup \{\|T(Sf)\|: f \in V \text { and }\|f\| \leq 1\}$. But don't really know where to go from here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Equality is not true.

Comment: I guess you meant $\|T\circ S\|\le\|T\|\|S\|$

Comment: Think about a nilpotent operator such as $\pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 1 & 0}$.

Comment: Oops yep I did sorry! I've edited it

Comment: If $U = V = W = \Bbb{R}^2$, and $S$ and $T$ are the orthogonal projections onto the $x$ and $y$ axes, then $S \circ T = 0$, but $||S|| = ||T||= 1$.

Comment: Hint: think about what the definitions of $\|S\|$ and $\|T\|$ tell you given your correct description of $\|T \circ S\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\|T \circ S\| = \|S\| \cdot \sup\left\{\left\|T \left(\frac{Sx}{\|S\|} \right)\right\|: f \in V \text{ and } \|f\| = 1\right\}.
$$

Comment: Why is this true?  I've managed to get from the hint to the answer though, thank you.

Comment: @CharlieSandberg for any set $A \subset [0,\infty)$ and $k > 0$, we have
$$
\sup(A) = k \cdot \sup \{a/k : a \in A\}
$$

Comment: @CharlieSandberg Another approach is to simply use the inequality $\|Sf\| \leq \|S \| \cdot \|f\|$.